# Showing a tag cloud by author

Tags: expressionengine

I have a site that has many users, each with their own mini-site. Part of this 'mini-site' is a blog. I'd like to show a tag cloud for each author. The basic cloud feature of Tag and Tagger will do this, but for ALL authors. Adding an author_id doesn't work.

I tried to use a channel entries loop to get all the entries by author, then show the tags associated with these entries.

```
{exp:channel:entries author_id="1" channel="blog"}
{exp:tag:tags entry_id="{entry_id}"}
<li>{title}<a href="#">{tag_name}</a><span>{total_entries}</span></li>
{/exp:tag:tags} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This did get me a list of tags that only that Author has used (in Tag, it didn't work in Tagger). However if a tag was used more than once it would list it more than once.

Native EE and Tag functionality won't let me do what I want to do. I'll probably need to use php (a plug in) to do this. Fetch all the tags an author has used, put them in an array, remove duplicates, then output this into my template. I did post at Solspace, but they said I'd need to use PHP.

Before I did that I wanted to see if there is a simpler method or some other add-on that can do this. I would also welcome any tips on approaches in such a plug in if that is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Tagger and the Query Module you should be able to get what you need (probably Solspace Tags, too, I just haven't used that one so can't say for sure).

A query like this

```
SELECT tag_name  
FROM exp_tagger
WHERE author_id = 7
```

Gives a set of tags for that author.

You can use it with the Query Module like this, using the current entry's `author_id` as a dynamic part of the query.

```
{exp:query sql= "SELECT tag_name FROM exp_tagger WHERE author_id = {author_id}"}
    {tag_name}
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: This probably will do the job if the data is stored that way in the DB. You'd need to use SELECT DISTINCT to get only unique tags.

Comment: Handily, that table in the Tagger module only has one record per tag, and a field for `total_entries`, so it works with a plain `SELECT`.

Comment: Wow, very easy. I ruled out Query module thinking it too would grab duplicates. However looking at the database each tag is only listed once as such it will only pull each tag once. I am using 
    `{exp:query sql= "SELECT tag_name, total_entries FROM exp_tagger WHERE author_id = 1"}`

It is working in Tagger, I'll give it a shot in Tag to see if that works as well.

Comment: It does work in Tag as well BUT...there is a problem in Tag and Tagger.

Whoever used the tag first is the author. So if another person were to use the same tag, it would not show up in their tag cloud. Considering these users will be writing about similar topics, this would likely be an issue. 

However this exercise did really open my eyes to how important it is to look into the database and see what data is in there and how it is constructed. The Query module is a powerful but often overlooked aspect of EE. I may need to use a plugin, and if I do I'll be sure to post it here for others.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that, but it totally makes sense. You and @MediaGirl are right, this will need a custom plugin. In case you aren't familiar with it [Pkg.io](http://pkg.io/) is a useful tool for generating starter files for building add-ons. The official docs on [plugin development](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/plugins.html) as well as this [tutorial](http://expressionengine.com/blog/entry/building_a_plugin_replacing_magpie) might also help you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think your only option here is custom PHP to remove the duplicates.